# Source code of the screens of debian-installer

Tags: debian, source

Where do I can find the source code of the screens of the installation process of Debian?

I've tried: *apt-get source debian-installer*

But in this package I do not see the source code.

To be more specific I'm looking for the source code of this screen:

[image]

Comment: If you want to know *how* it's done, almost certainly via [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), which has bindings for most high level languages.

Comment: But, where is the source code?

Answer (score 12):

Debian Installer is actually a bunch of different packages, in several repositories. The Debian Wiki has a page on [how to get the Debian Installer source](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/CheckOut): Make sure `mr` is installed, and:

```
svn co svn://anonscm.debian.org/svn/d-i/trunk debian-installer
cd debian-installer
scripts/git-setup
mr -p checkout
```

Beware it'll take a while, as its ~480MB.

The particular dialog you're interested in comes from:

- packages/partman-base/debian/partman-base.templates
- packages/partman-base/choose_partition/*
- packages/partman-base/display.d/manual_partitioning
- a bunch of .po files with translations to many, many languages

(The easiest way to find that is with `ack-grep`...)

Note that it's asked via Debconf, like the rest of the installer. So the same source drives the similar dialog in the graphical installer.

Comment: You can also specify -rHEAD at the end of the svn command to speed up that part a little.

It's also not the size of all the checkouts that matters, it's more that there's *112* unique repositories that have to be checked out.

If you don't mind putting extra load on the already slow anonscm.debian.org, `mr -j8 -p checkout` will speed it up, assuming you have the bandwidth